# intelligently using the ellipsis in an R function

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I had a function with a signature like this:

```
myFunction=function(class="Class",v1='y',v2='y',dfparam=df){
```

where `df` is a dataframe and it is assumed that there is an attribute called `Class` in df.    I wanted to make it more general so that it can accept a variety of dataframes, df, not just one that has an attribute called Class.
So I added in a `className` parameter and `classValue` parameter to replace the class parameter. Also, I want to allow unlimited arguments v1, v2, v3 etc. and so I am using the elipsis like this:

```
myFunctionGeneral = function(className="Class", classValue="democrat", dfparam=df, ...){
  arguments <- list(...)
```

Prior to using the elipsis, I had a line that used the arguments as follows:

```
X_bool=dfparam$V1==v1 & dfparam$V2==v2
```

I started out doing this:

```
X_bool=dfparam[,2]==arguments[1] & dfparam[,3]==arguments[2]
```

but I want to do this for an unlimited number of possible paremeters in the elipsis.
So I need to **expand** this statement by somehow unraveling the ellipsis.
Here is an example:

```
install.packages("vcd")
library(vcd)
data(Arthritis)
AAr=Arthritis[,-c(1,4)]


myFunctionGeneral=function(className="Class",classValue="democrat",dfparam=df, ...){

  dfparam$names<-rownames(dfparam)
  arguments<-list(...)


  dfparamDroppedClass=dfparam[,-1]
  #X_bool=dfparam[,2]==arguments[1] & dfparam[,3]==arguments[2] 
  X_bool=do.call(all, Map("==", dfparamDroppedClass, arguments))


  X=dfparam[X_bool,]


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should illustrate the principle:

```
arguments <- list(1, 2, 3)
params <- list(1, 2, 3)
do.call(all, Map("==", arguments, params))
#[1] TRUE

params <- list(1, 2, 4)
do.call(all, Map("==", arguments, params))
#[1] FALSE
```

All is equivalent to an arbitrary number of `&`, and `Map` iterates `==` over the two lists.

**Edit:**
Apparently your data.frame has more than one observation. Then you can't use `all`, but need to use `Reduce` as in `Reduce("&", Map("==", arguments, params))`. With your example:

```
myFunctionGeneral=function(className="Class",classValue="democrat",dfparam=df, ...){

  dfparam$names<-rownames(dfparam)
  arguments<-list(...)

  dfparamDroppedClass=dfparam[, -c(1, 4)]
  #X_bool=dfparam[,2]==arguments[1] & dfparam[,3]==arguments[2] 
  X_bool=Reduce("&", Map("==", dfparamDroppedClass, arguments))

  dfparam[X_bool,]      
}

myFunctionGeneral('Treatment','Placebo',AAr,'Male','Marked')
#   Treatment  Sex Improved names
#4    Treated Male   Marked     4
#5    Treated Male   Marked     5
#6    Treated Male   Marked     6
#8    Treated Male   Marked     8
#14   Treated Male   Marked    14
#52   Placebo Male   Marked    52
```

Comment: Thank you. I think arguments<-list(...) is analogous to your arguments <- list(1, 2, 3), but I also need a list that contains dfparam[,2], dfparam[,3] and so on but it also has to be of the same size as arguments dynamically and has to begin with 2 not 1. Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: A data.frame is also a list. And you know how to remove the first column of a data.frame, don't you?

Comment: Thanks! I tried this: dfparamDroppedClass=dfparam[,-1] and then this: X_bool=do.call(all, Map("==", dfparamDroppedClass, arguments)). But I get a warning Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter.    And also the function I am writing does not generate the right output. When I run it with this: X_bool=dfparam[,2]==arguments[1] & dfparam[,3]==arguments[2] , it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, I won't invest more time without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: I called it with this: myFunctionGeneral('Treatment','Placebo',AAr,'Male','Marked')

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the same warning when replacing X_bool=dfparam[,2]==arguments[1] & dfparam[,3]==arguments[2]   with  X_bool=Reduce("&", Map("==", dfparamDroppedClass, arguments)).  I will have to study your suggestion.